# Get Value from Custom Control in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I am modying from legacy code that is using `Grid_CellEditEnding` - I modified the grid to use a custom control:

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="cellQty" Header="Qty" Width="1.1*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Resources:NumericTextColumn  Text="{Binding Qty}"  >
                                </Resources:NumericTextColumn>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Resources:NumericTextColumn  Text="{Binding Qty}"  >
                                </Resources:NumericTextColumn>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And once the cell event triggers I am trying to get the value of the object but am having difficulty casting the object (getting presentation framework errors)

```
 private void Grid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
                if(e.Column.Header.ToString().Equals("Qty"))
                { 
                   //this is in error             
                 var newQuantityText = ((NumericTextColumn)e.EditingElement).Text; 
                }

        }
```

Comment: is the Grid_CellEditEnding event is getting called ?

Comment: Yes it is - just need to get the value from E that is the Numeic Text Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the `DataContext` Property of the row and casted with Class Type to get Property. Instead of Data Class you need to provide your Class which has Qty Property.

```
 private void Grid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
            if(e.Column.Header.ToString().Equals("Qty"))
            { 
                 var d = ((Data)e.Row.DataContext).Qty;
            }
    }
```

***Updated Answer***

In order to get the current entered data, in the grid row.

```
private void Grid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
            if(e.Column.Header.ToString().Equals("Qty"))
            { 
                 var NumericDataCtrl= GetVisualChild<NumericTextColumn>(e.EditingElement);
                    var data  = NumericDataCtrl.Text;
            }
    }
```

To access the child Control inside EditingElement, I used the below method

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual

    {

        T child = default(T);

        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)

        {

            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            child = v as T;

            if (child == null)

            {

                child = GetVisualChild<T>

                (v);

            }

            if (child != null)

            {

                break;

            }

        }

        return child;

    }
```

Comment: Testing now - will let you know

Comment: All the properties of the class in the data context are null but I like the direction you are going with this.

Comment: Was there records in the row ? or was it only empty record ?

Comment: Just an empty record

Comment: That's why you are having all Properties as Null, Now enter any data and then move to any other record and then come back to the same record and then edit cell the data will be present, Reason for this is we are in Editing mode , CellEditEnding